# Preg_replace: How to strip the hyperlinks, but only if the hyperlink contains particular text

Tags: php

I want to strip away hyperlinks, so only the text remains.  So that

```
<a href='www.mysite.com/directory/'>Click Here For My Site</a>
```

Simply becomes

```
Click Here For My Site
```

I have this so far and it works:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<a.*>(.*)</a>#isU', "$1",  $content);
```

HOWEVER, I only want to strip the hyperlink away IF the hyperlink contains the specific test 'directory' in it.

In that case, the link below, which does not contain the word 'directory', would NOT be stripped of it's hyperlink.

```
<a href='www.mysite.com/FORUM/'>Click Here For My Site</a>
```

I cannot figure out how to do this!  Whatever I try doesn't seem to work... :(

Comment: using preg_replace will cause most likely security holes. is this user submitted content? is ther priveledged content on your site? user log ins? you may not want to allow ANY html tags to be placed on your site or you will be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: It's only content on my own wordpress blog, content that I wrote myself.  No user log-ins to the blog, except for the admin who is myself.  So would security still be an issue?...

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+directory[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/isU', "$1",  $content);
```

This will grab the text in the hyperlink as long as there id the word "Directory" in the opening `<a>` tag

Comment: That worked.  Thanks Geoffrey, you're awesome.  Next time I'll just ask here instead of spending 3 hours flailing!!!